# Woocommerce product images not shown after shared on facebook

Tags: facebook, woocommerce

I use the plugin "Woocommerce social button" to share my products on social networks like Facebook. Unfortunately, the product image's is not displayed on the Facebook post (it's my website logo which is displayed).

I solved it by installing "Yoast SEO" plugin and set in the product Social -> Facebook section the default image of the product.

I want a script or a plugin doing that automatically.

Don't know how to start cause, i'm not a Wordpress developer.

Thanks for helping me !!!.

Answer (score 0):

Yoast is a good one unless you already use another SEO plugin.

The image is specified as a meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/product-image.png"/><meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.example.com/product-image.png"/>
```

More information about the same is available at:
http://ogp.me

Answer (score -1):

Install YoastSEO Plugin
In YoastSEO select "Social"
go to "Facebook" Tab
Keep enable "Add Open Graph meta data"
That's it
Now your product images will be appear on Facebook post...!